# Can I use more than one custom tableviewcell nib file in a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, nib

I want to put different cells in a table, and all of them is kind of complexity, so I want to use nib for these cells. However, i really don't know how to use multiple cells in a table. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as many custom UITableViewCells as you want in a single UITableView. The issue here is: What kind of logic do you want to implement? Only you can define it. You can start by using this tutorial to see how to implement the custom UITableViewCells:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

You can then reply to my answer to tell me what logic do you to implement. For example:

- first 3 cells one with a type of UITableViewCell, then 3 with different UITableViewCell.
- Alternate between cells (for instance, 4 different UITableViewCells in a row)

You need to specify what you need. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I put two different xib for cell to display my data and give them different identify string. It works.